# Stop loading the page if Javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cross-browser

I have a Rails web app (Online Examination System). I have disabled Right click, selection, copy etc using JavaScript in the examination interface. So, I want my app to detect whether JavaScript is enabled on interface start up. I have checked it by using `<noscript>` tag as follows.

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
            <div id="noscript_message" style="color: white; background-color: red;">
            It is detected that Javascript is turned off in your web brower. Please turn it on to load the page correctly. For more reference about how to turn it on, please refer <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
 instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.
            </div>
</noscript>
```

But I could only detect and show up a message as warning. My intention is not to load that page and show up the warning message only. How that can be achieved?

Thanks :)-

Comment: `<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" ...></noscript>`, but it is damned ugly. You shouldn't disable right click, copy, etc... that is sooo old school...

Comment: Kindly mention the reason for down voting..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `no-js` class on your `body` element and hide it with CSS, then show it with JavaScript so if users have JS disabled they get an "empty" page.

```
<body class="no-js">
```

In CSS:

```
body.no-js { display: none; }
```

Then in JS:

```
document.body.className = "";
```

Comment: `document.body`... don't over complicate `:)`

Comment: <body> tag has already a class name assigned for with other specifications. Then?

Comment: You can use jQuery or replace it: `document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('no-js','')`

Comment: @elclanrs: Hey, How can I detect 'javascript is enabled' in javascript file? Inside that checking only, I can furnish the above statements

Comment: but anyone with even basic knowledge of html/css will change that `display:none` to `display:block` and bypass the check, no? Is there any way to REMOVE the content entirely